# Enable github copilot in Neovim for shell command editing

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, neovim

I use bash and like to use the built-in command <kbd>Ctrl x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl e</kbd> to invoke an editor in the shell in order to edit the current line.

This creates a temporary file, named `/tmp/bash-fc.[Some random alphanumeric string]`, and once that file is saved, whatever you have written gets executed.

Since I have my EDITOR environment variable set to neovim, it's possible for me to turn github copilot on while I'm editing my shell command with the vim command: `let b:copilot_enabled = v:true`

This is very cool for on the fly scripting. However, since copilot looks for file extensions, I can't turn it on by default without having it on permanently whenever I start nvim.

I thought of mapping a key to the command `let b:copilot_enabled = v:true` with  in my .vimrc, but I can't get it to work. Looking for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure Vim to automatically set the filetype based on other criteria that the mere file extension.

In your `~/.config/nvim/ftdetect/bash` you can add the following line:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead bash-fc[-.]* set ft=bash
```

You have to use `set ft=bash` instead of `setfiletype bash` because Vim already set the filetype to `sh` for this pattern.

If you Vim distribution also set the filetype of this pattern to `sh` maybe could you use the `sh` filetype to activate copilot.

Comment: Just brilliant. This works!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) If it solves your  problem you can accept the solution using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It let the question rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Vivian De Smedt's answer is great.
Mapping a custom key like so:
`map <[KEY CODE HERE]> :let b:copilot_enabled = v:true<CR>` 
can turn Copilot on as well.